# Connect to WiFi using iOS app with GUI User Request not Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, wifi

Since adding WiFi Network Programmatically in iOS is nearly impossible without jailbreaking the Iphone :(

Is it possible to make an application to provide wifi password hidden in stars ******** and ask the user to click on a button in app and connect to wifi network with the hidden password?,

What i mean is: the idea: 
Application provides the wifi password without user seeing the plain text password, 
but can click a button to open an Intent (dialog or something with the password provided and press connect manually) to connect to WiFi with the hidden WiFi password **( GUI User Request NOT Programmatically )**

Is it possible to do that in Swift or Objective-C without jailbreaking the iphone?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You must register your app as a HotSpot Helper to get access to the required API within the NetworkExtension framework.

Take a look at [NetworkExtension.NEHotspotHelper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspothelper) and the [Hotspot Network Subsystem Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/Hotspot_Network_Subsystem_Guide/Contents/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016639-CH1-SW1)

For future questions, please provide some code showing what you have tried so far. This makes it easier for others to provide a helpful solution and it's easier for other people looking for a the same solution.

Comment: Sorry i didn't provide code, because i am not an iOS developer, i am android developer, and i have an application that works really nice on android, but it doesn't work on iOS because of this matter, so i've been trying to find a solution for this problem for almost 1.5 Years, 

so after i found this idea, and asked about it, now you guys helped me solve 50% of the main problem, the other remaining problem is (Forgeting WiFi Password on Iphone) cannot be done programically so at least the app will ask the user to forget current WiFi password in the iPhone, if he wants to connect to a new one

Comment: Can it be done using User GUI Request ?, just like adding?, in the above question?, 

PS: i am gone start programming on iOS when i find a perfect solution for my problem :), Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

You have to use MultipeerConnectivity for GUI wifi connection.

Step1: import MultipeerConnectivity

step2:

```
   var browser : MCBrowserViewController!

   var assistant : MCAdvertiserAssistant!

   var session : MCSession!

   var peerID: MCPeerID!
```

step3:

```
    Add  MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate, MCSessionDelegate
```

step4:

```
    self.peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)

    self.session = MCSession(peer: peerID)

    self.session.delegate = self

    self.browser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType:serviceType,
                                           session:self.session)

    self.browser.delegate = self;

    self.assistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType:serviceType,
                                           discoveryInfo:nil, 
                                                session:self.session)

    self.assistant.start()
```

step5: Next use session delegate methods.

I think it's helpful.

Comment: Using `MultipeerConnectivity` only provides a session for a set of devices to share data using Wi-Fi or bluetooth, i don't see how this solves OP's question?